# Recursive retrieval of "Subject" fields for defect reports in QC 11

Tags: sql, recursion, hp-quality-center

On HP Quality Center 11.0:

I need to make a recursive read of the labels in the "Subject" branch for a set of defects. I can tell that the server is app. not an Oracle one as the sys_connect_by_path "cheat" does not work. Instead I'm stuck with recursive SQL which I, for lack of brain power, cannot complete.

The principle is: From the table bg_bug, get an item and list recursively the set of entries in all_lists.al_description until NULL.

Sort of:

retrieve all items in the BUG table
get its parent and print the linked contents of all_lists.al_description
check if the parent has a parent and if it does, get that parent and print the linked contents of all_lists.al_description, concatenating it with the string retrieved for its child
repeat until orphan.

I found this in a different thread:

with t1 (parent, child) as  (select * from all_lists t where t.al_father_id = '2') select * from t1

which cannot be executed as it contains "invalid statements". I gather from that thread that the "with" statement is disallowed when using SQL in Quality Center.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the statement with a select statement so

```
select * from 
(
with t1 (parent, child) as (select * from all_lists t where t.al_father_id = '2') select * from t1
)
```

Comment: I still get the "Incorrect syntax near keyword WITH" error message.